# Can someone please verify that my An is diverging

Tags: real-analysis

Given $A_n=\{1+1/2+1/3+1/4+. . . +1/n\}_{n=1\dots\infty}$ where $\varepsilon>0$ and $\forall n\ge N$

Using Cauchy theorem which states: A sequence $A_n$ is not a Cauchy sequence if there exists $\varepsilon>0$ such that $\forall n,m>N$, $|A_n-A_m|>\varepsilon$

Consider $\varepsilon=1/5$ pick $n=2N$ and $m=N$. Then
$$|A_n-A_m|=|A_{2N}-A_N|=|(1+1/2+1/3+1/4+\dots+1/N+1/(N+1)+\dots+1/(2N))-(1+1/2+1/3+1/4+\dots+1/N)|
=|1/(N+1)+\dots+1/(2N)|>1/5=\varepsilon$$
so $|A_n-A_m|>\varepsilon$ so it's not Cauchy and by definition: If a sequence $A_n$ is not Cauchy then it doesn't converge.

Comment: This is quite confusing. What is $N$? You may be asking if/why the harmonic series diverges  - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)

Comment: It is easier to note that $A_{2n}-A_n=$ $\sum_{j=n+1}^{2n} (1/j)\geq$ $\geq  \sum_{j=n+1}^{2n}(1/2n)=1/2.$

Answer (score 1):

Show $\int_1^{n+1}$ 1/x dx < 1 + 1/2 +...+ 1/n.
Since the integral diverges, so does the sequence.

Your claim that a certain sum < 1/5 lacks a proof.